# Python: gather exception statistics

Tags: python, exception

I am repeating a sequence of experiments (with random initialization) like this in Python:

```
num_rounds = 1e3
result_list = []
for i in range(num_rounds):
    result = run_experiment()  # with random initialization inside the call of `run_experiment`
    result_list.append(result)
```

However, my code can be buggy and exceptions might be thrown halfway, which will then interrupt the whole loop.

I'm wondering if there a way to:

1. let go the exception and continue the loop
2. meanwhile, store the condition (input parameters) that causes the exception(s) somewhere
3. gather basic statistics of different exceptions, for example the frequency of each exception type.

Or is there already a tool to do that?

Answer (score 1):

1) Let go exception and continue loop:

```
try:
    <whatever code can cause exception>
except <Exceptions you want to catch>:
    pass
```

that will catch the exception and let it slip. Alternatively you can put a continue in the except block:

```
try:
    <whatever code can cause exception>
except <Exceptions you want to catch>:
    pass
```

2) and 3) With the code from 1. you can collect any data you want in the except block and then do a continue:

```
statistics_list = []
for <something>:    
    try:
        <whatever code can cause exception>
    except <Exceptions you want to catch>:
        statistics_list.append((exception_type, input params....))
        continue
```

after your loop you can process the data in your statistics list to your liking

Answer (score 0):

There is `try..except..else`:

```
num_rounds = 1e3
result_list = []
exceptions = {}

for i in range(num_rounds):
    values = 1,2,3, ... # with random initialization outside the call of `run_experiment`
    try:
        result = run_experiment(*values)  
    except Exception as e:
        exceptions[values] = e
    else:
        result_list.append(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will be able to do your statistics if modify your code like this

```
num_rounds = 1e3
result_list = []
for i in range(num_rounds):
    try:
        result = run_experiment()  
        result_list.append(result)
    except Exception as ex:
        # do statistics
```

That way you have the exception as `ex`, you can check and store the type.
If you also want to store the random input parameters than you should put the same `try-except` in your `run_experiment` function